# Using ArcPy to select polygons one by one and export them?

Tags: arcpy, select, error-000358, split-by-attribute

I want to select polygons in a (double field type) and export them, and I keep getting this error:

> ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression "dobule" = '1'
>   Failed to execute (Select).

This is my code

```
outws = r'F:\Documentos\ArcGIS\Default.gdb'
shp = r'F:\Documentos\ArcGIS\ensayo'
campos = 'dobule'
y= "_"+str(int(row[0]))
         out_fc = os.path.join(outws, y)
         where_clause =  """"{}" = '{}'""".format(campos,arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(shp, row[0]))
         arcpy.Select_analysis(shp, out_fc, where_clause)
```

Comment: The error message is quite specific. Have you not tried removing the quotes around the double value? Note that equivalence comparisons for floating-point types are notoriously risky, since so many values are not representable.

Comment: Thank you Vince!, I didn't realize that. Removing the quotes works pretty fine

Comment: This looks like a use case for the Split By Attribute tool.

Comment: I'm currently using ArcMap 10.4, and that tool is only available for ArcMap 10.6

Comment: Looks like it came in at 10.5: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/analysis-toolbox/split-by-attributes.htm